# git stash equivalents in other revision control systems?

Tags: git, version-control

Does hg, svn or others have an option like git stash?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The general name for that feature is:

**Shelving**: the ability to actually upload intermediate revisions to the server without really checking them in.
In a CVCS (Centralized VCS), you actually need to upload those intermediate data to a central server.
But in a [DVCS (Distributed VCS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917), you just need to store them in a the local repository.

There is:

- the [shelve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension) for Mercurial
- [temporary branches for SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554278/temporarily-put-away-uncommited-changes-in-subversion-a-la-git-stash), or [patch files](http://www.benrady.com/2009/09/svn-replacement-for-git-stash.html)
- [p4tar](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4tar) (again patch based) for Perforce, even though the [Perforce 2009.2 has now shelve and unshelve features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104184/is-there-an-equivalent-to-git-stash-in-perforce/2105898#2105898).
- [saved checked-out data in Plastic SCM](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2006/11/branching-and-shelving.html) (for shelving data)

You can find all the other SCM shelving commands in this [SCM comparison table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software#Advanced_commands).

- Accurev: <del>keep / co</del> (this is disputed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19765112/6309))
- Bazaar: shelve / unshelve
- Darcs: revert / unrevert

Comment: Alternately, for Mercurial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158419/hg-mercurial-any-way-to-set-aside-the-working-copy-for-later

Comment: Possibly WP has changed since this answer, but Accurev's entry shows no support for shelving :(

Comment: @MattSach Yes, this must have changed after this 2013 question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19765112/6309

Answer (score 5):

Jazz Source Control, integrated in IBM Rational Team Concert supports this functionality. It is called "Suspend".

From the Jazz.net site: "Jazz allows you to temporarily remove a change set from your workspace by suspending it. At some point in the future, you can resume the change set and continue working on it."

[Jazz Source Control FAQ](https://jazz.net/library/article/126/)

Comment: This isn't really equivalent because its not intermediate. When you "suspend" you have removed it from your workspace but the check-in has occurred (the component has a new changeset)

Comment: When you _Suspend_ a Changeset, the _code_ is removed from your Local Workspace **and** from your Repository Workspace. It is in your component but only as a "Shelved" or "Suspended" changeset. That means that if someone loads that repository and compiles the project it will **not** contain those changes.

So, in what sense is this different from Shelve or Stash?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use shelves, you can do it the following way.

```
hg diff > mylocalchanges.txt
hg revert -a
# Do your merge here, once you are done, import back your local mods
hg import --no-commit mylocalchanges.txt
```