# stage part of line

Tags: git

Is it possible to stage only part of a line?

Scenario:
I am refactoring my unit tests from Rhino.Mocks to NSubstitute, so I am changing a lot of code like this:

```
mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.MyMetod());
```

to this:

```
mock.Received().MyMetod();
```

Now, I am not finished with this refactoring, but while I am at it, I come across a typo in one of my methods and fix it, so the code will look like this:

```
mock.Received().MyMethod();
```

Now, the renaming of this method is completely unrelated to the refactoring from Rhino.Mocks to NSubstitute, so I just would like to commit this change in its own revision. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there is no telling how much you already modified your code, I would rather:

- [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272923/git-stash-equivalents-in-other-revision-control-systems/3272973#3272973) all my pending changes
- `reset --hard HEAD` (make sure you don't have non-indexed changes, as in "changes only on your hard drive, never added to a Git repo": they would be deleted)
- make the refactoring, add it and commit it
- git stash pop: restore the changes
- fix the last `MyMetod` call that your pending changes were still using

Comment: Do you really mean to stage all pending changes? Or rather to *stash* them?

Comment: What do you mean by non-indexed changes? "changes only on your hard drive" -> My complete git repo is only on my hard drive, so this explanation is rather ambiguous :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: yes stash (typo). As for the "non-indexed" part, I mean file that are unknown to git (never added, never committed).

Comment: ok. Is the `reset --hard HEAD` really necessary? AFAIK `git stash` already resets the working copy.

Comment: I just tested it: stashed the changes (this automatically reset my working directory) and did the rest as you said. Worked like a charm! :) Thanks a lot