# Is there RTC-equivalent "Suspend mode" in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I found "Suspend Change-set" in RTC to be very useful, and since we're working with ClearCase as well (dozens of users) I'm wondering if that feature is also available in ClearCase as well.
If not - could it be generated by script/trigger/hook ?

We use UCM, and I'd like to explain my question:
if I have to deliver and I want to skip delivering one activity, I can decide not to deliver it (if no dependencies...) , so my question is regarding working on my *current* stream: Is that possible to "suspend"  an activity from my *current* stream ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, not easily.

RTC is basically ClearCase rewritten from scratch, and the "suspend" mode ([also called stashed or shelve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272923/git-stash-equivalents-in-other-revision-control-systems/3272973#3272973)) takes advantage of the notion of applying a changeset (to any state of a repository)

The UCM changeset are a list of versions of files. Each version is tied to its predecessor, and you cannot easily remove it (unless you do some [negative or subtractive merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636712/evil-twin-problem-and-subtractive-merge/1637405#1637405)), and then re-apply them later.

---

That being said, [Reuven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798178/reuven) just contacted me this morning, because he had files in checked out in a snapshot view on a Stream which he wants to rebase (similar issue to your deliver problem).

A possible way to do that is to create another view (dynamic one), which you can use for your rebase, and then go back to your snapshot view and update it: it will detect the updated config spec (following the rebase) and will *not* erase any of your currently checked out files.
On the checkin, those files will be merged with the updated version.