# What is a 'Pending Patch' in RTC source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Within my 'Pending Changes' view I see this :

[image]

What are 'Pending Patches' and how are they created ? I think someone may have inadvertently created it. I do not seem to have the options to see what files have changed, should I not have this option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pending Patch is a diff waiting to be applied in your local workspace.

It can be the result of a merge, or the explicit removal of a changeset ("Suspend"), put aside as a "Patch" (again, a diff), in order to clear the current local workspace of a modification you don't want to apply just yet.

You can also create one when [accepting an incoming changet](https://jazz.net/library/article/126#AcceptWithGaps):

> Accepting a change set will work when all previous change sets it depends on are present in your repository workspace.
>   When one of those change sets is missing then there is a [gap in history](https://jazz.net/jazz/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/170658).
>   RTC SCM prevents an accept from completing in this scenario.
>   There are two options to get the change into your repository workspace:
>
> 1. Accept the change sets that will fill the gap. This may be as simple as accepting all incoming changes if the change set you want is in your incoming changes.
> 2. Accept the change set and select the option to **accept as a patch**.
>      This will create changes that you can merge into your Eclipse workspace and check-in. A new change set would be created that will not depend on the change sets that would fill the gap.

[image: Accept as Patch]

The [Help page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_scm_patch.html) explains how to *create* a patch.

Note that there is no easy way to get the same feature in ClearCase.
See:

- "[Is there RTC-equivalent “Suspend mode” in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110401/is-there-rtc-equivalent-suspend-mode-in-clearcase/8112509#8112509)"
- "[git stash equivalents in other revision control systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272923/git-stash-equivalents-in-other-revision-control-systems/3272973#3272973)"