# What would be a good introdcutory tool to Clearcase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I am developer with more than 10 years of software development experience. I have joined a new shop which uses ClearCase and I would like to understand ClearCase. Any suggestions for a developer who has pretty good hands on the following SCMs

- Subversion :
- Perforce : written extensive build scripts integrating with perforce
- Mercurial

Let me say the IBM documentation is pretty scary and I am looking for a quick tutorial which will help me understand the ClearCase commands

Comment: Having been in a very similar position as you about a year ago, all i can say to you - is Best of Luck!! :-)

Comment: Thanks InSane (and everybody else too)! been through some introduction to clearcase and I must say I find this an archaic tool. I wonder how IBM can continue to charge such hefty fees for such a product. The good news is the company has already realized this and is in the process of moving over to a DVCS (probably git). But till that time I will have to live with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand the [**basic concepts** on which ClearCase operates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771).

Then you need to understand how to [take advantages of some of its unique features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449549/how-to-leverage-clearcases-features).

And of course, you need to be [aware of its **disadvantages**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074580/clearcase-advantages-disadvantages).

You also need to understand the selection mechanism and the [difference between snapshot and dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378).

---

Please note that the ClearCase config spec (with its selection based on **composition**) is quite different from DVCS or SVN, based on a unique id for selecting a given history revision.
See [Flexible vs static branching (GIT vs Clearcase/Accurev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763099/flexible-vs-static-branching-git-vs-clearcase-accurev/764219#764219).

In that regards, the UCM methodology (which comes with ClearCase, but which can be ignored at first, or even used in parallel with "Basic ClearCase" views) introduces the notion of UCM components ([akin to Git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals)).

Answer (score 0):

[Software Configuration Management Strategies and IBM Rational ClearCase: a Practical Introduction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Software-Configuration-Management-Strategies-ClearCase/dp/0321200195/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1282905225&sr=8-3) Will teach you everything that you need to know about Clearcase

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to interact with clearcase. The graphical and the command line. The graphical is much easier and intuitive and is the best option. The problem is that for a large repository the interaction with the GUI can be slow. 
Whatever you do using the GUI you can do via the command line as well.
If you do a help in the cleartool you will see all the commands and their description.
What you need to read is what is a view and how to create one. Then how to set the appropriate specification for the view and then you can start working with the files.
After the setup the rest is straightforward. You checkout a file, modify it and check it in.
Hope this helps.