# How can I retrieve a file through Label in Config Spec?

Tags: clearcase

I have labelled a file "`Test.java`" with a label called "`My_Label`".
When I try creating a view with the below config specs, I am unable to get the file in Clearcase Explorer.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * My_Label
```

Could anyone please tell where am I going wrong in the above config spec?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, but I'm no pro user. Have you tried putting each `element` statement in a separate line? Also, double-check the label name, perhaps it's just a typo...

Comment: @SvenS the rules were on separate lines (I have edited the OP for adding the right format). As for the actual cause, see my answer: if that rule doesn't apply to one of the parent directories, nothing will get selected.

Comment: Ah, I see, that tricky stackoverflow formatting again :)

Answer (score 7):

That selection rule alone isn't enough.

You need to add,  *before* that rule, other rules that will select the right version of the *parent* directories.

In other words, if your parent directory (or one of the ancestors) of Test.java isn't labelled with My_Label, it won't be selected *at all*.
So your file won't be accessible by your view, even though you have the correct selection rule for you file.

Check if the Vob itself has been labelled with MyLabel.

If not, I would recommend at least to add one final "stop" rule (`/main/LATEST`: see "[ClearCase Branching using configspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245768/clearcase-branching-using-configspec/4246525#4246525)" for an illustration of that rule):

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * My_Label
element * /main/LATEST
```