# ClearCase dynamic view doesn't show empty files

Tags: clearcase

We usually use snapshot views and they work just fine.
However, I tried to use a dynamic view recently and doesn't show empty files in the working directory. We use Python so namely, it doesn't show empty `__init__.py` files, which breaks most of our code. All other files in the same directory, and non-empty `__init__.py` files exist.

Is this a known issue? What can I do?

---

Running `cleartool ls` says about the `__init__py` file: "no version selected".

My config spec looks something like this:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * SubComponenet1_VersionX
element * SubComponenet2_VersionY
element * SubComponenet3_VersionZ
element /src_base /main/LATEST
```

Assuming the empty files are inside `src_base` and considering the last rule, how can a file not have a selected version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try a `cleartool ls` in the parent directory of those file, in a shell or a DOS windows.

You can see there status, and see if they are selected by your config spec.

Check also that the config spec of your dynamic view is similar to your snapshot view:

- `cleartool catcs` within your snapshot view
- `cleartool edcs` from your dynamic view

For a non-UCM dynamic view to reflect an UCM snapshot view, it can be pretty complex.
It is best to create a dynamic UCM view on the same Stream.

At the very least, your config spec should end with a [stop-rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529284/6309):

```
element * /main/LATEST
# or
element /src_base/... /main/LATEST
```

Your last rule is only for /src_base directory, and not for the sub-elements.

Comment: My snapshot view is a UCM view and its config spec is pretty complicated.

Comment: @AndyThomas is your dynamic view an UCM view on the same stream?

Comment: @AndyThomas I have edited the answer to add more information.