# How to unmount unwanted VOBs ( large number of VOBs) from clearcase dynamic views in windows

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

My project uses clearcase 8. we have around 10 dynamic views ( streams ). Each dyanamic view contains 5 VOBs.

After importing these dynamic views in windows clearcase explorer, all the 50 VOBs are appearing under each and every dynamic view ( though majority of the irrelevant VOBs contains just lost+found directory under it).

Once I have manually unmounted all of the irrelevant VOBs from the corresponding dynamic views but after a restart of my PC all the VOBs are appearing again every where.

I don’t want to view all the 50 VOBs in each dynamic view.

Is there a solution for this issue ?

PS: - I am not a clearcase admin / expert.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can [`cleartool umount`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm) all vobs with

```
cleartool umount -all
```

Secondly, you can mount them without making them persistent:

```
cleartool mount \aVob
```

Through the GUI, they are generally mounted as "persistent", like if you did:

```
cleartool mount -persistent \aVob
```

That means they are recorded in the Windows registry, in oprder to be mounted again automatically at the next Windows session.
If you mount them through a script, without the `-persistent` option, you won't have that problem.

Finally, know that if one of your dynamic view need a vob, then you need to mount it (obviously).
But that same vob will then be visible on *all* your dynamic views (it will be mounted at least, even if no version in it is selected by the other views config spec).

To resolve that, you can add in another dynamic view which shouldn't see a particual vob:

```
element /aVob/... -none
```

(you can use '`/`' and not '`\`' in a config spec, even in Windows)

That will make that vob invisible for that dynamic view, while still being mounted and available for the first dynamic view which needs it.

Comment: Thank you VonC. When i right click on my windows dynamic view, i can only see foundation baselines, i dont see any place where i can amend the config spec to add "element /aVob/... -none". please suggest.

Comment: @Subba I am more a command-line of guy than a GUI user ;) But even with the GUI, when selecting properties on a dynamic view, you can access the "Config Spec" tab, in which you can add any rule you like. Example in command-line of config spec modification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656418/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1346985/6309. The last link brings actually more details on how and where put that "non-selection" rule in your config spec.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a bat file and use it to mount a list of VOB's using
cleartool mount \vobname

Comment: They should not have been.  I actually had free time to go through a bunch of topics that interest me (almost all ClearCase).   I trully meant the up vote.  I even marked some of the topics as favorites since it is stuff that I want to keep until I can move the data into my permanent notes.  You got the bulk of the upvotes since your posts are typically quite detailed and you usually answer questions.  I also added answer two or three answers to some posts.  I guess next time I have to spread it out over several days which means it probably will not happen which is unfortunate.