# Difference between remounting and rebooting

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In my windows cc client, Is it the same thing that I remount and unmount the vobs or reboot my pc? when I reboot, does it automatically unmount the file system and remount all the vobs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't the same thing.

Mounting or unnmounting a vob allows said vob to be visible in *all* **[dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)**, in your `M:\yourView`, for any dynamic view that you have started.
That manages the Vob on your [MVFS drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172362/6309) (a device installed on your PC to manage dynamic access to the Vob server content).

Restarting your PC won't necessarely remount your vob(s).
It will mount your vobs only if you have modified the ClearCase settings in order to specify "**Reconnect at logon**" (See "[To mount/activate VOBs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_activate_vob.htm)").

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21231111&aid=3]

See also "[How to unmount unwanted VOBs ( large number of VOBs) from clearcase dynamic views in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17020430/6309)" in order to make *some* vobs to be mounted (reconnected) at logon automatically (option `-persistent` of [`cleartool mount`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm))