# rebasing config spec in clear case

Tags: clearcase

I am new clearcase I am trying to rebase the branch m_tool. Could you please tell me how should i go about rebasing for the following config spec?

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * DATASOURCE
element /entities/... /main/LATEST 
element * .../m_tool/LATEST 

mkbranch m_tool
element * .../branch2011/LATEST 
element * TAG_2010_OCT_02
element * .../m_dd_lt_hfix/LATEST 
element * TAG_2010_02_DEV_BASE
element * /main/LATEST 
end mkbranch m_tool
```

Thank you,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**[Rebasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852488/6309)**" is a merge between a parent UCM stream and a direct child Stream.

What you show is a base ClearCase config spec, not an UCM one.

That config spec would show the latest on `m_tool` branch, and, for version which haven't yet any `m_tool` branch:

- the latest of `branch2011`
- or, if no `branch2011`, the tag `TAG_2010_OCT_02`
- or if no tag `TAG_2010_OCT_02`, the latest of branch `m_dd_lt_hfix`
- or, if no branch `m_dd_lt_hfix`, the tag `TAG_2010_02_DEV_BASE`
- or, as a **[stop rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529284/6309)**, the latest of `main` branch

In each case, if a version is done, you would create it on the `m_tool` branch.

If that is what you mean by "rebasing", then it is correct.

> I want m_tool to have everything, instead of looking at each tags/branch.

Then you would need to merge a view which display only non m_tool versions:

```
element * .../branch2011/LATEST 
element * TAG_2010_OCT_02
element * .../m_dd_lt_hfix/LATEST 
element * TAG_2010_02_DEV_BASE
element * /main/LATEST
```

And merge that view an m_tool-only view:

```
element * .../m_tool/LATEST 
element * /main/0 -mkbranch m_tool
element * /main/latest -mkbranch m_tool
```

Comment: Hi VonC, 

Thanks for your explanation. I want m_tool to have everything, instead of looking at each tags/branch. Do you know how is it done?

Thank you,
Dennis

Comment: @DennisWong Then possibly do a merge of non-m_tool versions into an m_tool view. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi VonC,I don't quite understand the concept of stop rule. Can you please explain a little more? I saw the link you have attached.

Comment: @DennisWong  a stop rule is a selection rule that will *always* be used, because there is *always* a `/main` branch, and *always* at least one version (the version 0). So any rule you put *after* that `element * /main/LATEST` will *always* be *ignored*, because the selection process *stopped* at the "stop rule".

Comment: I just tried to rebase each branch and tag one by one. I got an error saying that this config spec only support branch to brach rebase. Do you happen to know why? Thanks!

Comment: @DennisWong what do you mean "rebase"? Are you actually using UCM? Can you edit your question with a screenshot of the error?