# ClearCase config spec rebasing

Tags: clearcase, rebase

I need to merge all sub-branches into `m_tool` so that I can get the desired config spec.

I am trying to use my company's rebase tool but I get an warning saying that my config spec only supports branch-to-branch rebasing.
Could you please tell me what do I need to do?
I understand that `element * TAG_2010_OCT_02` and `element * TAG_2010_02_DEV_BASE` are tags.

This is my desired config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * DATASOURCE
element /entities/... /main/LATEST 
element * .../m_tool/LATEST 
mkbranch m_tool
element * /main/LATEST 
end mkbranch m_tool
```

This is my original config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * DATASOURCE
element /entities/... /main/LATEST 
element * .../m_tool/LATEST 

mkbranch m_tool
element * .../branch2011/LATEST 
element * TAG_2010_OCT_02
element * .../m_dd_lt_hfix/LATEST 
element * TAG_2010_02_DEV_BASE
element * /main/LATEST 
end mkbranch m_tool
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using UCM inter-project deliver, then your error message ("config spec only supports branch-to-branch rebasing") really depends on the way your company merge tool is implemented.

What you can try ([similar to what I suggested to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19961808/6309)) is:

- keep your original config spec
- make a second view with a target config spec like:

  ```
  element * CHECKEDOUT
  element * DATASOURCE  -mkbranch m_tool
  element /entities/... /main/LATEST  -mkbranch m_tool
  element * .../m_tool/LATEST  -mkbranch m_tool
  element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch m_tool
  ```

And try merging what you see in the first view to the second view.
But again, that depends on the exact capabilities of your company merge tool.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. By merging, do you mean I should a clean check out of both the "original" and "desired" config spec, copy all files from the "original" view to the "desired" view, and then check in all files to the "desired" view?

Comment: @DennisWong I mean you can use the first view as a source of the merge, and the second as the destination, using a tool like the [ClearCase Merge Manager](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/u_mrgman.htm)