# clearcase symbolic link file not visible from a snapshot view

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, clearcase-remote-client, clearcase-automation

I have created a symbolic link (see below) to a version controlled file from a different vob (`VOB_II`) and the file is visible from a dynamic view whereas it’s not visible from the UCM snapshot view.

```
A.txt --> ..\..\..\VOB_II\SampleDir\A.txt
```

I have the following selection and load rules.

```
element \VOB_II\SampleDir\A.txt ...\branch1\LATEST
load \VOB_II\ SampleDir
```

Any ideas why the file is not getting loaded in the snapshot view? I could not figure out what’s wrong. Any help or inputs are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, do a `cleartool ls` in `C:\path\to\my\view\VOB_II\SampleDir`

The status can explain why the element is not loaded.

Typically, you need selections rules that selects *also* the parent folders (`SampleDir` and `Vob_II`) *before* being able to select `A.txt`.

I would recommend at least adding an `element * /main/LATEST` ([stop rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529284/6309))

```
element \VOB_II\SampleDir\A.txt ...\branch1\LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
load \VOB_II\ SampleDir
```

---

Second, it looks like you are trying to load the actual A.txt (the one in `VOB_II\SampleDir\A.txt`), and not the symbolic link one the `A.txt` pointing to `..\..\..\VOB_II\SampleDir\A.txt`

I don't know where is that symbolic link `A.txt`. In `Vob_I`?

---

Third, see "[Symbolic links in snapshot views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/c_symlinks_ssv.htm)"

> Snapshot views created from Linux or the UNIX system maintain standard symbolic link behavior.
>
> In the context of loading a snapshot view, links are treated as:
>
> - VOB links (those that point to objects inside the VOB) and
> - non-VOB links (those that point outside the VOB).
>
> Hard VOB links are followed; symbolic links are copy-created.
>   If a VOB link cannot be resolved, an error results.
>   Non-VOB links are resolved, if possible, but it is not an error if they cannot be resolved.
>
> Snapshot views created from a Rational ClearCase host running **Windows software** do not support links.
>   VOB symbolic link behavior is approximated in the following ways:
>
> If a load rule selects a symbolic link, the link target is copied into the view at the link path.

Comment: A.txt is in VOB_II and the snapshot view is loading VOB_II\SampleDir; but not A.txt. When i do cleartool ls it says " A.txt --> ..\..\..\VOB_II\SampleDir\A.txt [not loaded]"

Comment: @user2705120 if `A.txt` is in `VOB_II`, why `..\..\..\Vob_II\SampleDir\A.txt`? Why not `..\..\SampleDir\A.txt`?

Comment: @user2705120 As for the "not loaded" status, I suspect the selection rules don't select the right version of the parent folder: display a version tree of ``SampleDir\`` to see which version is selected in your snapshot view.

Comment: Sym Link was created in VOBI...The issue was with the selection rule and once i fixed the selection rule to load SampleDir, it worked. Thanks for your advise and it helped.

Comment: @user2705120 Great! What selection rule did you used?