# Can't Create Directory Element With Multi-Branching in Base ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I am workng with base ClearCase. Please consider my config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT

element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/*/... /main/rel_drop5/int_drop5/cl5_p65719_AUTE/LATEST

element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/*/... /main/rel_drop5/int_drop5/LATEST -mkbranch cl5_p65719_AUTE
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/*/... /main/rel_drop5/LATEST -mkbranch int_drop5
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/*/... /main/0 -mkbranch rel_drop5
```

INTENT: Any checkout of existing elements automatically occurs on branch `/main/rel_drop5/int_drop5/cl5_p65719_AUTE` and that this branching scheme is used automatically for the creation of any new elements (of which I presently have none).

When I navigate to the root of VOB cl5_sw_ste in ClearCase Explorer, select New--> Folder from the right pane's context menu, and try to create my first element---directory element DCT---, I receive the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why is this occurring?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those selection rules are for elements *inside* `DCT`, not for `DCT` itself.

When you are adding `DCT`, it creates a version in `/main/0`.
And none of your rules selects `/main/0`.

you should add least add one selection rule at the end:

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

That is called a "config stop-rule", as illustrated in "[ClearCase Branching using configspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245768/clearcase-branching-using-configspec/4246525#4246525)".

Comment: What would be the difference between: element * /main/LATEST and element /cl5_sw_ste /main/0? The intention is to not have any versions on main except for 0.

Comment: @Dave `element /cl5_sw_ste /main/0` only applies to the Vob root directory `cl5_sw_ste`, not to any of the sub-elements within that root directory. `element * /main/LATEST` applies to *any* element (Vob root directory and everything in it)