# No Directory Element Version is Selected

Tags: clearcase

I have the following config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/rel_drop5/int_drop5/cl5_p65719_AUTE/LATEST
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/rel_drop5/int_drop5/LATEST                 -mkbranch cl5_p65719_AUTE
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/rel_drop5/LATEST                           -mkbranch int_drop5
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/0                                          -mkbranch rel_drop5
element * /main/0
```

This config spec does not let me see a directory element named DCT that lives in the root of VOB cl5_sw_ste. DCT has the following version tree:

```
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\0
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\0
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\int_drop5
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\int_drop5\0
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\int_drop5\cl5_p65719_AUTE
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\int_drop5\cl5_p65719_AUTE\0
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\int_drop5\cl5_p65719_AUTE\1
```

I would have thought that config spec rule:

```
element /cl5_sw_ste/DCT/... /main/rel_drop5/int_drop5/cl5_p65719_AUTE/LATEST
```

Would have selected:

```
cl5_sw_ste/DCT@@\main\rel_drop5\int_drop5\cl5_p65719_AUTE\1
```

However, no version is selected. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out what version of the *parent* directory of DCT is selected, which is the vob `cl5_sw_ste`.

If it is `/main/0`, then this is normal: this **[is a placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309333/why-i-only-get-a-clearcase-version-0/5309714#5309714)** which won't contain sub-elements.
Which means nothing under the vob `cl5_sw_ste` will be selected, nor visible.

Your last rule should be:

```
 element * /main/LATEST
```

That would allow to select at least `/main/1` of the vob `cl5_sw_ste`, which should contain the directory `DCT`.
That is why I mentioned this stop-rule in your previous question "[Can't Create Directory Element With Multi-Branching in Base ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14715198/6309)".

Comment: Our project's policy requires that all elements, including cl5_sw_ste, branch off of /main/0. No versions other than 0 are allowed on /main. My "element * /main/0" rule failed because I mistakenly created version cl5_sw_ste@@/main/1 when I added directory element DCT.

Comment: @Dave ok, it makes sense then.