# Is this config spec good enough?

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

I am more a UCM rather than Base CC guy. Can anyone tell me if this config spec is good?
I have some doubt at the last line. Is that ok without a `element * /main/LATEST`?

---

~~~~~~ below is the request from the developer ~~~~~~~~~

i hope to have all their changes in the `/main/nz_plusOne` branch, even when they check-out file from `/main/nz_mig`.

What does their config spec look like? I think it's something like

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/nz_plusOne/LATEST
element * NVAR_NETEZZA_3 -mkbranch nz_plusOne
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch nz_plusOne
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always ends with `element * /main/LATEST` (a ["stop" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14715198/6309)), because you don't know if *all* the elements have a version in `/main/anotherBranch`.

In your case, the usual config spec would be:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/nz_plusOne/LATEST
element * NVAR_NETEZZA_3 -mkbranch nz_plusOne
element * /main/0 -mkbranch nz_plusOne
element * /main/LATEST
```

> when they check-out file from /main/nz_mig

If they have a file checked out (in any branch), you won't see that version from your view anyway (it only selects checked out version that *you* did in your view.