# sync two vobs file (by clearfsimport) without checking in the updated file

Tags: linux, version-control, clearcase

I am using following command to sync B vob files from A vob

```
clearfsimport -master -follow -nsetevent -comment $2 /vobs/A/xxx/*.h /vobs/B/xxx/
```

It works fine. But it will check in all the changes automatically. Is there a way to do the same task but leave the update files in a check out status?

I want to update the file for B from A. Build my programme, and then re-cover the branch. So if the updated files is an check out status, I can do unco later. Well with my command before, everything is checked in. I cann't re-cover my branch then.

Thanks.

---

As VonC said, it's impossible to prevent "clearfsimport" to do the check in. And he suggested to use a label to recover back.

For me, the branch where I did "clearfsimport" is branched from a label.Let's call it LABEL_01. So I guess I can use that label for recovery. Is there an easy way (one command) to recover the files under /vobs/B/xxx/ to label LABEL_01 ? I want to do it in my bash script, so the less/easy the command is, the better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a look at the [man page for `clearfsimport`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm), no, it isn't possible to prevent the checkins.

I would set a label before the clearfsimport, and modify the config spec for the new version to be created in a branch ([similar to this config spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896209/6309)).
That way, "re-cover" the initial branch would be easy: none of the new version would have been created in it.

Comment: Hi, the branch I did "clearfsimport" is branched from a label. So I guess I can use that label for recovery. Is there an easy way (one command) to recover the files under /vobs/B/xxx/ to label LABEL_01 ?

Comment: @thundium the easiest way would be to create another view with a config spec selecting only that label. Not exactly "one command" though.

Comment: @thundium one other option would be to reverse the config spec of your current view, and relaunch a `cleartool update` (for a snapshot view).

Comment: that's true, but that means I need to creat new branches each time I do the test. I'll think about it. Thanks for your suggestion.