# Clearcase Branch configspec

Tags: clearcase

I need to create a new VOB and a branch to access the newly created VOB.

The development will not be on a main branch, so I create a release branch.
Once the development is done, the release branch will be merged to main branch.

How do I write a config spec for the initial branch so that it is derived of `/main` branch?

```
element /new_vob/... .../rel_branch/LATEST
mkbranch rel_branch
element /new_vob/... /main/0
end mkbranch rel_branch
```

Please suggest if the above look good.
Also suggest if any base `LABEL` is required at the start, there is no source for the VOB.
The development will happen over time.

Answer (score 1):

If your new VOB is empty, you don't need a LABEL as a base for your `release` branch.
The **[placeholder version 0 of `/main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309714/6309)** is enough.

Your (non-UCM) config spec would simply be:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../release/LATEST
# (not needed yet) element * LABEL -mkbranch release
element * /main/0 -mkbranch release
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
```

Once you have done one release, merged to `/main`, then it is a good idea to make a `LABEL` on `/main`, and make a new `release2` branch starting from `LABEL`.

You can replace '*' by `/new_vob/...` if you want.
(If it is a dynamic view, with only `new_vob` mounted, it would have access only to `new_vob` anyway)

Comment: Thank you VonC. As my activity requires config spec to select the branch and not the /main , can i have the below config spec:                                   element * CHECKEDOUT
mkbranch release                                                                         
element * .../release/LATEST
element * /main/0
end mkbranch release

Does the above makes sense?

Comment: @Narasimha if you don't add the rule `element * /main/0 -mkbranch release`, that means you won't be able to "add to source control" a new file.

Comment: VonC, i have this line element * /main/0, can i skip element * /main/LATEST?

Comment: @Narasimha I would not skip that rule: it is a stop rule (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14715198/6309), that I mention for instance in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18896209/6309

Comment: Thank you VonC, this helps.