# ClearCase label problems: nobody except me can observe the files I labeled

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I made a branch with a cleartool cmd line utility with:

```
cleartool> mkbrtype BRANCH_NAME
cleartool> mkbranch BRANCH_NAME
```

Next I specified mkbranch in the configspec for the view I am working with like

```
element * .../BRANCH_NAME/LATEST
mkbranch BRANCH_NAME
element /vob_name initial_label
end mkbranch
```

Next I checked out files of interest, applied a patch of mine to it and checked the changes in with the UI utility.

Right after I've done with it I applied:

```
cleartool> mklbtype label_name
cleartool> mklabel -recurse label_name vob_name
```

Everything seems fine when I put this label instead of initial_label - I see the changes I made. Unfortunately its only me who can see the contents of vob with this my label.

Question: What I have done wrong and how I can fix this problem?
PS: I created a different view with the same configspec and in this view the vob also empty for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately its only me who can see the contents of vob with this my label

You can debug this by asking a colleague to do a version tree on one of the elements that you checked out/checked in in the new branch.
That version tree can be done from any version of that file.

If the new branch is visible in the version tree, and your colleague doesn't see your modification in his/her ClearCase view, that simply means their config spec isn't the same as yours, and isn't set top show the LATEST versions from that new branch.

The [OP Zorgiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466198/zorgiev) adds [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280897/clearcase-label-problems-nobody-except-me-can-observe-the-files-i-labeled/28281694?noredirect=1#comment44920038_28281694):

> under different view I see my version as a `RESERVED` and the version number is not specified within the circle.
>   I suspect it thinks that the file is still checked out (RESERVED), but actually I checkd in my changes.

I confirmed: all files need to be checked in before setting up a label. Or only the view which has those files checked out would see them.

Beside the `RESERVED` should be the name of the view in which the version is checked out.

---

The OP adds:

> We managed to get changes observable through the change in the configspec like:

```
element /vob_name/... label_name -mkbranch BRANCH_NAME 
element /vob_name/... /main/LATEST -mkbranch BRANCH_NAME
```

> What is the problem here? How do others make their branches/labels so that nobody needs to specify vob elemennt name twice like in this example? They make their labels so that I can just specify the label name once

I detail what kind of config rules are needed for branch creation in "[ClearCase Branching using configspec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246525/6309)".

In particular, a stop rule (one always true) like `element /myVob /main/LATEST` is very important.

Comment: But if they don't specify the branch name explicitly but rely only on the label I gave them, doesn't this mean they must automatically get the changes from the label I gave(I mean the branch I checked chanhes into)?

Comment: PS: I created a different view with the same configspec and in this view the vob also empty for me.

Comment: @Zorgiev they will only if *all* the parent folders (`/avob`, `/avob/folder1`, `/avob/folder1/folder2`, ...) have been labelled as well. If one level is mission, the view won't be able to access and display the versions below.

Comment: I tried to re-apply label with Apply Label Wizard(Set up "Move existing Label" option) and this have no effect.

Comment: @Zorgiev yes, but the label needs to be applied from the very top as well (but not recursively or you would end up applying the label to *everything*). Once you now that you must label everything within `/avob/folder1/folder2`(which you can do with the Wizard), *then* you need to apply that label as well on `/avob/folder` (and just that folder, nothing else), and then on `/avob` (and just that vob root directory, and nothing else).

Comment: I need to label entire VOB with all the versions it contains. And so do I when I use Apply Label Wizard.

Comment: Maybe something is wron with the branch/type I created? This very operation succeeded earlier.

Comment: @Zor Simply do a version tree on each parent folder, all the way up to the vob root directory, and check if that label is there for a version of each folder.

Comment: Actually I see entire vob with the same configspec in another view as empty. But let me try checking your suggestion.

Comment: under different view I see my version as a RESERVED and the version number is not specified within the circle. What does it mean?

Comment: I suspect it thinks that the file is still checked out(RESERVED), but actually I checkd in my changes.

Comment: @Zorgiev I confirmed: all files need to be checked in *before* setting up a label. Or only the view which has those files checked out would see them.

Comment: We managed to get changes observable through the change in the configspec like:

    element /vob_name/...                      label_name -mkbranch BRANCH_NAME
    element /vob_name/...                      /main/LATEST -mkbranch BRANCH_NAME
What is the problem here? How do others make their branches/labels so that nobody needs to specify vob elemnt name twice like in this example? They make their labels so that I can just specify the label name once.

Comment: @Zorgiev I have edited the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4246525/6309 is an instructive read.

Comment: But in my main view where I checked chages in if I specify thils label name in configspec without additional branch information - I get my chenges fetched.

Comment: @Zorgiev true, it needs to be tested in a separate view.