# clearcase create a branch into another branch

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

I have a branch created into the main with this config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/teste_branch_nv0/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch teste_branch_nv0
element * /main/LATEST
```

Now, I want to create other branch into this branch. I am trying to use:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/teste_branch_nv0/teste_branch_nv1/LATEST
element * /main/teste_branch_nv0/LATEST -mkbranch teste_branch_nv1
element * /main/teste_branch_nv0/LATEST
```

but, I have a mistake:

```
Problems performing setcs.

ClearCase CM Server: Error: Unable to determine version for VOB root directory element.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Unable to access "\PROJECT\IMPLEMENTATION\Fonts\ENVIRONMENT\workspace": No such file or directory.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: 1 config spec load rule problems encountered.
```

This is the same path that I use to create the branch `teste_branch_nv0`

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have left out the rule

```
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch teste_branch_nv0
element * /main/LATEST
```

The "stop rule" `element * /main/LATEST` is particularly important, because it is the one rule that will always apply.

If you have an element (like the root folder of your Vob) for which *no* rule apply, then you would get

```
Unable to determine version for VOB root directory element
```

That is why you should always keep as a last rule the `element * /main/LATEST`  selection one.

See as an example "[ClearCase Branching using configspec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246525/6309)".

It will also show you that the LATEST selection rules should be written as:

```
element * .../teste_branch_nv1/LATEST
```

Because you don't know from which branch (`main` or `teste_branch_nv0`) the new `teste_branch_nv1` branch will be created.

So the full config spec should be:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../teste_branch_nv1/LATEST
element * .../teste_branch_nv0/LATEST -mkbranch teste_branch_nv1
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch teste_branch_nv1
```

Comment: Actually, the last line is redundant. You will never select that line as the selection clause is identical to the previous line.

Comment: @BrianCowan True, I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: But, I don't want that the branch teste_branch_nv1 be created linked with main. I want he linked with teste_branch_nv0. Can I use only: "element * /main/LATEST" in the end?

Comment: @RodrigoRicha yes. That will limit the `teste_branch_nv1` to be created only from `teste_branch_nv0`.

Comment: Thanks one more time

Comment: I think it depends on whether you want checkouts from /main to be on /main itself, /main/...nv1 or /main/...nv1/...nv2. If you want checkouts in main to stay in main, then no -mkbranch clause after element * /main/latest works. If not, then we are into "that depends on what you want to happen" territory.