# ClearCase Snapshot View Not Updating

Tags: clearcase, snapshot, config-spec

I am using ClearCase for the first time, and am having a little trouble understanding snapshot views. I have a view with the config spec

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/dev/LATEST
load "\project\dir1"
load "\project\dir2"
load "\project\dir3"
```

I am using the same config spec with a dynamic view without the load rules. I have checked in a file called "configSpecTest.txt" into "\project\dir1\subdir", and this shows up in my dynamic view.

However, after calling

```
cleartool update
```

and being told it successfully updated, the file is not there in my snapshot view. I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how snapshot views work. Could anyone please explain to me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a config spec like:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../dev/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch dev
load "\project\dir1"
load "\project\dir2"
load "\project\dir3"
```

You should always need the last selection rule `element * /main/LATEST` because to load/access an element, you need to load/access its parent element, and it is possible that `/project` does not have any version in the `dev` branch.

While your element is visible in your dynamic view, try and see if it is visible in *another* dynamic view with your original config spec mentioned in your question.

Try and create again your element with your dynamic view and the config spec mentioned above: that is how you create new branches for element.
See more at "[ClearCase Branching using configspec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246525/6309)"