# ClearCase claims directory is both checked out and not checked out

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, vcs-checkout

I am using Jenkins to manipulate files and directories in Base ClearCase. I am executing the batch file

```
cd /D M:\view\path\to\stuff\Jenkins
echo Test to see if Jenkins can add things to ClearCase> foo.txt
cleartool checkout .
cleartool mkelem foo.txt
```

and I get the output

```
M:\jenkins_dynamic\CSTS\01_Build\Automated_Build\Jenkins>cleartool checkout . 
cleartool: Error: Element "." is already checked out to view "jenkins_dynamic".

M:\jenkins_dynamic\CSTS\01_Build\Automated_Build\Jenkins>cleartool mkelem foo.txt 
cleartool: Error: Can't modify directory "." because it is not checked out.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your dynamic view config spec, as [in this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21142784), with [`cleartool catcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_catcs.htm):

```
cleartool catcs -tag jenkins_dynamic
```

> The cause of this error relates to the current view's config_spec; it may have a `-mkbranch` rule or use an existing branch name for a branch type that is not mastered at the local site.
>
> If the parent directory can't be checked out on the non-mastered branch, then new elements can't be created in that directory.

Example: this [config spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414449/6309) (without the loading rules, since you are in a dynamic view).
Make sure all the parents folders are accessible and visible.

So that kind of error could be in the context of a multi-site ClearCase.

Comment: How would I check if a directory can't be checked out on the non-mastered branch? It's strange because it says that I am checking out the directory 'Jenkins', but then saying I can't modify it because it isn't checked out.

Comment: @ChristianBouwense First: what version of ClearCase are you using? Is it multiSite?

Comment: ClearCase version 7.1.2.19, not multiSite.

Comment: @ChristianBouwense OK, what is your config spec?

Comment: I don't think I can give you that information since it's technically proprietary, but I can say that I'm starting with 
element * CHECKEDOUT
and that the directory which I'm trying to check out is not on the main branch, but I am selecting for it. (Btw thanks for helping me out with this!)

Comment: Is there a mkbranch rule? What cleartool ls returns in the parent folder of the folder which should be checked out?

Comment: There are no mkbranch rules.
This is the result of cleartool ls in the parent directory of the directory I'm trying to check out (namely \Jenkins)

M:\jenkins_dynamic\CSTS\01_Build\Automated_Build>cleartool ls 
foo.txt
Jenkins@@\main\dev\B_Windows7Candidate\6                 Rule: ...\B_Windows7Candidate\LATEST
readme.txt@@\main\dev\1                                  Rule: SIRN12187
SIRN11796xx_latest@@\main\dev\1                          Rule: SIRN12187
SVD_Generator@@ [no version selected]

Comment: @ChristianBouwense Without a mkbranch rule as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414449/6309, you won't go very far.