# What's the equivalent in Git to a read-only component in ClearCase?

Tags: git, clearcase, git-submodules

My company is in the process of changing our version control tool from Rational ClearCase to Git.  We have the following development scenario, and we're curious if there's a proper pattern to follow with Git to achieve the same behavior we have in ClearCase.

Here are some basic points about our situation:

> 1. We have a number of discrete applications.  Let's call these AppA, AppB, and AppC.
> 2. We also have certain files (build scripts, etc.) that are common to all of the projects.  Let's call this Tools.
> 3. For any given cut of the AppA, AppB, or AppC code, we need a specific cut of the Tools code.
> 4. Most of our developers never modify the Tools code.

For ClearCase, we've modeled this like this:

> Components: app_a, app_b, app_c, tools
>
> Projects: AppA, AppB, AppC, Tools
>
> Project AppA includes app_a as a read/write component and tools as a read-only component.
>
> Project AppB includes app_b as a read/write component and tools as a read-only component.
>
> Project AppC includes app_c as a read/write component and tools as a read-only component.
>
> Project Tools includes tools as a read/write component.
>
> Each baseline for the App* projects references a baseline on both the app_* and tools compoments.  When developers rebase to the recommended baseline, they pull in changes from *both* components.

For Git, we think submodules might be the closest thing to the right answer.  However, when pulling/rebasing a repository, it sounds like it requires an extra step to update the submodule code.  Ideally, we'd like to be transparent.  Also, we don't necessarily care about knowing what changed in a submodule from the viewpoint of the parent repository; we only care about a point in time for the entire submodule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be sure to understand the difference between a (UCM-like) configuration in ClearCase and git (see "[Flexible vs static branching (GIT vs Clearcase/Accurev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763099/flexible-vs-static-branching-git-vs-clearcase-accurev/764219#764219)").
When looking at the [differences between ClearCase and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771), each UCM components must be represented in Git as a repository.

Submodules requires an extra step if modified, as described in "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)".
But they record a specific SHA1, which is what you want when you are pulling each '`APP`'.
[gitslave](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/) would allow you to keep `Tools` more tightly linked with '`Appx`', but I don't think it fits your scenario.

Note that using submodules will:

- make '`Tools`' a sub-directory of '`APPx`'
- make it modifiable.
  There is no "read-only" component with git: if you can access the repo, you can push/pull.
  If you really need to enforce a read-access, then you need to add an extra "authorization layer", called **[gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/index.html#what)**.